# socket.io Updating all the open pages

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to create a chat website, something like a discord clone. I am using socket.io to connect my front end and back-end but I cant figure out how to make it that when someone enters a message that message to be displayed on all currently open browser pages

Server.js (My server file I use):

```
        const express = require("express");
    const app = express();

    const http = require("http").Server(app);
     const port = 4000;

      const io = require("socket.io")(http);


          app.get("/", (req, res) => {
             res.sendFile("ChatRoom.html", {"root": __dirname});

          });

           io.on("connection", (socket) => {
           console.log("A user has connected");
        socket.on("messageSend", (data) =>{
          console.log(data);

         io.emit("chatUpdate", data);
          });

         });



      http.listen(port, () => {
             console.log("Server.js listening on port " + port );
         });
```

And my Javascript code in the HTML file:
                                    var socket = io();
              document.addEventListener('keydown', InputText);

```
            function InputText(e)
         {

  //Checks if the pressed button is Enter and if the input box is empty
  if( e.keyCode == 13 && document.getElementById("chat_input").value != "")
      {


    //Gets the div which the message will be ridden to
  var parent = document.getElementById("chat");
  //Current date to be used when displaying the exact time of sending the 
     messgae
  let d = new Date()//.getTimezoneOffset();

  //Getting the properties of the input
  var value = document.getElementById("chat_input");

  //Telling the server that a message has been sent - function
  emitter(parent, value.value, d);

  //Setting the text box back to blank
  value.value = "";

  }
 }
//Function
    function emitter(holder, text, date){

  socket.emit("messageSend", text);

  socket.once("chatUpdate", (message) => {
    var z = document.createElement("p");
    z.innerText = date.getHours() +":"+ date.getMinutes() + " | " + 
        message;
    z.style = 'border-top: 1px solid Black;border-bottom: 1px solid 
           Black;font-size:20px; margin: 0;padding: 10px;';

    holder.appendChild(z);

   });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have emitted the message you need to be listening for it in the client, if the action you are trying to achieve is sending the message to another user that has the socket currently open on their window. Because you are sending it to a user not the server, so you would need to be connecting to the socket so it's very possible your socket might need to be defined more like this.

`var socket = io.connect('Your:/url/of/windowlocation/whileonsocket/here')`

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my code it is defined as `var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");`
@Ashton Hauser

Comment: Have you listened for the socket emit on the client as well?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, my client was checking for messages only when the InputText function was called but I had to check for updates all the time, but now I have the problem that the very first msg doesnt pop up on all client pages